# Get user groups in OpenLDAP with JAVA

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

I don't know java that much but I need to change a code. The background here is we have the code working in LDAP which will give us the groups assigned to the user which has logged in. Now, we have to switch to OpenLDAP for some reason and here the problem arises. Here we are not able to get the groups assigned to the user.

Previously I was using to get the groups

The context name is here ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search 
    = context.search(contextName, 
            "(sAMAccountName=" + userId + ")", constraints);
```

Now, I have tried various combination like

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search 
          = context.search(contextName, 
                   "(uid=" + userId + ")",  constraints);
```

and

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search 
        = context.search(contextName, 
                "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=+userId)",  constraints);
```

and others.

The problem is here I am not getting the groups name. So, is there wrong in how I am searching for groups or what I am not getting. Could anyone please help me.

This is our code

```
public static HashMap getGroupList(
        DirContext context, String userId, String key) 
        throws NamingException, NullArgumentException, 
                InvalidStringValueException, ParserException {

  //setting sonstraints ans searach control to subtree scope
  HashMap groupList = new HashMap();
  SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
  constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);
  constraints.setReturningAttributes(new String[]{"cn", MEMBER_OF_ATTRIBUTE});

  String contextName = parser.getConfigNodeValue("contextName");
  logger.debug("Context Name: " + contextName);
  logger.debug("Finding Group List for user ID: " + userId);
  NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search 
          = context.search(contextName, 
                  SAMAC_COUNT_NAME + userId + CLOSE_BRACKET, constraints);

  //searching attribute
  logger.debug("searching attribute");

  SearchResult searchResult = null;

  String value = "";
  while (search.hasMoreElements()) {
      searchResult = search.next();
      String groupName = searchResult.getAttributes().get(MEMBER_OF_ATTRIBUTE).toString();
      groupList.put(groupName, groupName);
  }

  return groupList;
}
```

EDIT:

here context name is `ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com` and I have applied the various search filter as `(uid=userId)`, also `(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(uid=userId))`, also `(&(objectClass=user)(uid=userId))`,  but I am getting nothing out. I need to know how to search in here.

Directory is simple here-

In **dc=maxcrc dc=com** there is **ou=People** 
and there is a user inside that demo and the demo has is a part of a group. Object class is inetOrgPerson for a user

Comment: Do you have the `memberOf` overlay loaded and configured? How? Was it there before you added users to groups? What is the value of `MEMBER_OF_ATTRIBUTE? What output is printed by your code? What is your question?

Comment: yes there were user added before, there was nothing coming in MEMBER_OF_ATTRIBUTE so the output was nothing. And my question is how can I get the groups names  to which the person is associated

Comment: That's 2-3 answers to seven questions. Try harder. By 'what is the value of `MEMBER_OF_ATTRIBUTE`?' I mean 'what is the value of that string constant'? If you got no search results it means the filter you searched on didn't match anything, not just that the `memberOf` attribute was empty.

Comment: Why are you using CLOSE_BRACKET when you are also using `(`? You're needlessly obfuscating your code here. The LDAP filter syntax is defined by an RFC and it is not going to change. You don't need to defend yourself against that. Just use `(` and `)`. And please *correct* your code. Two out of three of your search filters are mere Java syntax errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was wrong all the time. There is no memberof attribute in our OpenLDAP so the code will not work.

So I need to change the code a little bit such that I authenticate the user and then I should query every group present and check whether that username is present in those groups.

So, even if there is no memberof I can work out.

This is sample code I used-

```
import javax.naming.NamingException;


public class LdapQuery {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        SimpleLdapAuthentication obj = new SimpleLdapAuthentication();
        obj.ldapquery();
    }

}
```

and here is the method

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class SimpleLdapAuthentication {

    public String ldapquery() {
        String distName = "";
        String username = "cn=demo,ou=People,dc=saas,dc=com";
        String[] userID = new String[2];
        userID[0] = "Users";
        userID[1] = "Developers";
        int size = userID.length;
        String password = "sacs3";
        String groupName = "";
        String base = "ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
        //String searchFilter = "cn=" + username + "," + base;
        String ldapURL = "ldap://yourldapurl";
        Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        String[] returnAttribute = {"member"};
        SearchControls srchControls = new SearchControls();
        srchControls.setReturningAttributes(returnAttribute);
        srchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        for (int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++) {
            String searchFilter = "(cn=" + userID[i] + ")";
            try {
                DirContext authContext = new InitialDirContext(environment);
                //System.out.println("Authentication Successful");
                NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search = authContext.search(base, searchFilter, srchControls);
                // Probably want to test for nulls here
                distName = search.nextElement().toString();

                String[] splitBasedOnColon = distName.split("\\:");
                for (String x : splitBasedOnColon) {
                    if (x.startsWith("cn")) {
                        String[] splitGroupName = x.split("\\=");
                        groupName = splitGroupName[1];
                    }
                }
                if (distName.contains(username)) {
                    System.out.println("User is part of the group: " + groupName);
                }
            } catch (AuthenticationException authEx) {
                System.out.println("Authentication failed!");
            } catch (NamingException namEx) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
                namEx.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException notFound) {
                System.out.println("User is not part group : "+ userID[i]);
               // notFound.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return distName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are still wrong. If the `memberOf` overlay has been loaded and configured correctly and items added to groups subsequently there *is* a `memberOf` attribute on the entries specified in the configuration. The code you've posted here works, of course, but it is considerably less efficient than using the `memberOf` overlay correctly. Otherwise you may as well just uninstall it. I have `memberOf` code that has been working since 2009.

Answer (score 0):

> the output was nothing

That doesn't mean the attribute was empty. If that had been the case you would have seen the output of `logger.debug(groupName + " group name found for " + userId);`. As you didn't, clearly the search itself didn't return anything, i.e. something wrong with your filter or start DN.

**EDIT** Re your edit, only the first filter makes sense. The second one is a syntax error, and the third one searches the groups rather than the users, and it is the users that will have the `memberOf` attribute, not the groups. There is still not enough information here to comment further.

**EDIT 2**

> context name is `ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com`

OK.

> and I have applied the various search filter as `(uid=userId)`

Do you mean `(uid={0})` with a *parameter* of the value of `userId`? You should. And what *was* the value of `userId`?

> this also `(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(uid=userId))`

This is just nonsense:

1. There won't be (shouldn't be) groups under `ou=People`;
2. Group objects won't have a `memberOf` attribute. *Users* will have a `memberOf` attribute, showing what groups they are a member of. Looking for that inside the groups makes no sense whatsoever.

> this also `(&(objectClass=user)(uid=userId))`

See above. This requires that user objects have an `objectClass` of `user`. Do they? If not, what *do* they have, and why aren't you using that?

And *please* answer the question about what the relevant part of the directory tree looks like. Including the object classes.

Comment: could you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670197/search-user-groups-in-openldap

Comment: Don't create duplicates. If you want help with your search you will have to provide the actual search flter and search base, not gummed up with string constants, and also a snapshot of what the relevant part of the directory tree looks like.

Comment: NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search = context.search(contextName, "(uid= + userId +CLOSE_BRACKET,  constraints);....contextName is ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com means this is base, filter is uid= + userId and constraints is just number

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it is totally illegible.

Comment: I am just referring the internet and making changes in the code...I don't know much in openldap so sorry for the above silly mistakes...uid value is cn of the user and here when you told (uid={0}) means here I am giving the cn of the user like (uid={demo})? I have added class in question